# Could not create wake pipe. errno=24

Tags: android, picasso

App crash with error "Could not create wake pipe. errno=24"

```
Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(mContext);
                    builder.listener(new Picasso.Listener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso arg0,
                                Uri arg1, Exception arg2) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            arg2.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });
                    builder.memoryCache(new LruCache(Utils.MAX_CACHE_SIZE))
                            .build().load(image_url_list[position])
                            .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher).fit()
                            .centerCrop().into(imageview);
```

Comment: Do you read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606111/a-looper-could-not-create-wake-pipe-errno-24 ?

Comment: Thank you for replying @dtbeaver and yes i read this. But i want to configure the size of the memory cache ,so can you please help

Comment: errno 24 is EMFILE, and corresponding error message is "Too many file descriptors are in use by the process." So your or some other application is open too many files, I think.